# serverless warm up plugin concurrent execution of warmup functions

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I got the serverless-plugin-warmup 4.2.0-rc.1 working fine with serverless version 1.36.2

But it only executes with one single warmup call instead of the configured five.

Is there any problem in my serverless.yml config?

It is also strange that I have to add 'warmup: true' to the function section to get the function warmed up. According to the docs on https://github.com/FidelLimited/serverless-plugin-warmup the config at custom section should be enough.

```
plugins:
  - serverless-prune-plugin
  - serverless-plugin-warmup
custom:
  warmup:
    enabled: true
    concurrency: 5
    prewarm: true
    schedule: rate(2 minutes)
    source: { "type": "keepLambdaWarm" }
    timeout: 60

functions:
  myFunction:
    name: ${self:service}-${opt:stage}-${opt:version}
    handler: myHandler
    environment:
      FUNCTION_NAME: myFunction
    warmup: true
```

in AWS Cloud Watch I only see one execution every 2 minutes. I would expect to see 5 executions every 2 minutes, or do I misunderstand something here?

**EDIT:**
Now using the master branch concurrency works but now the context that is deliverd to the function which should be warmed is broken: Using Spring Cloud Functions => "Error parsing Client Context as JSON"

Looking at the JS of the generated warmup function the delivered source looks not ok =>

```
const functions = [{"name":"myFunction","config":{"enabled":true,"source":"\"\\\"{\\\\\\\"source\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"serverless-plugin-warmup\\\\\\\"}\\\"\"","concurrency":3}}];
```

Config is:

```
custom:
  warmup:
    enabled: true
    concurrency: 3
    prewarm: true
    schedule: rate(5 minutes)
    timeout: 60
```

Comment: Heya it doesn't look like they've done a release to get the concurrent warmup you'll need to point your package.json at the master branch in the repo! It seems the documentation got updated automatically but the npm release hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Yeah so from checking, they're actually in the process of installing one of the major contributers as the maintainer as the original chaps are way too busy and it is blocking the release for the feature you're looking for, just point your package.json at the repo for now let me know if you need a hand.

Comment: Thanks, concurrency works like a charm now!

   "serverless-plugin-warmup": {
      "version": "git+https://github.com/FidelLimited/serverless-plugin-warmup.git#1c19ff758c156d05e751e758322c881e0cf24c85",
      "requires": {
        "bluebird": "3.5.3",
        "fs-extra": "7.0.1"
      }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added Property sourceRaw: true to warmup config which generates a clean source in the Function JS.

```
const functions = [{"name":"myFunctionName","config":{"enabled":true,"source":"{\"type\":\"keepLambdaWarm\"}","concurrency":3}}];
```

Config:

```
custom:
  warmup:
    enabled: true
    concurrency: 3
    prewarm: true
    schedule: rate(5 minutes)
    source: { "type": "keepLambdaWarm" }
    sourceRaw: true
    timeout: 60
```